# What LEGO sets include minifigure with both arms and hands molded together?

Tags: minifigures

I was looking through my collection and found a minifigure torso with the arms and hands molded together. Does anyone know what set a minifigure like this came from?

Comment: Adding a photo to your question would be helpful...

Answer (score 3):

Torso with the arms and hands molded together sounds to me like the ones released with NBA basketball (so they can throw the balls better?)

[A list on Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=NBA%20arms#T=A)

[image]

Comment: It's subtle, but I think the word `both' threw me off - without it, this answer is clearly the best. Or perhaps "with hands and arms molded to each other" is clearer yet.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is technically still correct, but I thought it might not be what the asker had in mind, since they mentioned the hands at all.

Answer (score 2):

Bricklink calls it [Torso Legoland](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=17) (part 17).

[image: old one-piece torso]